# filter a date range using vba access 2007

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

I've got the following problem.
In my table is a field named "datum" This field is from a date type. this field is european
format (dd/mm/yyyy)
I also have a popupform, with two fields named "begindatum" and "einddatum"
When I fill in the dates in the popupform, all I want see the are records in the subform I selected in the popupform

Here is my code till so far,

**CODE**

```
Private Sub cmdFilterAan_Click()
    Dim strFilter As String


 If begindatum <> "" Then
    strFilter = strFilter & " And begindatum=#" & Format(CDate(Me.begindatum), "dd/mm/yyyy") & "#"
 End If

 If einddatum <> "" Then
    strFilter = strFilter & " And einddatum=#" & Format(CDate(Me.einddatum), "dd/mm/yyyy") & "#"
 End If

If naam <> "" Then
    strFilter = strFilter & " And naam=" & Me.naam
End If

If beroep <> "" Then
    strFilter = strFilter & " And beroep=" & Me.beroep
End If


If strFilter <> "" Then
    strFilter = Mid(strFilter, 6)
    Forms!frmData.FilterOn = True
    Forms!frmData.Filter = strFilter

End If
End Sub
```

The strFilter for "naam" and "beroep" are working fine, but for the date fields its not.
I think I'am looking for a BETWEEN statement in VBA code, how to do so I do not know.

When I fill in the dates in my popupform nothing happens, as a matter of fact the records
in the subform all disapears

Can anyone help me to solve thus problem.
thx in advance
greetings, ahc59

Answer (score 3):

Try passing your dates in mm/dd/yyyy format.  Filter seems particular about using that format.  So, for instance:

```
If begindatum <> "" Then
   strFilter = strFilter & " And begindatum=#" & Format(CDate(Me.begindatum), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
End If

If einddatum <> "" Then
   strFilter = strFilter & " And einddatum=#" & Format(CDate(Me.einddatum), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
End If
```

If you want to do between the dates, you can do:

```
If begindatum <> "" And einddatum <> "" Then
    strFilter = strFilter & " And begindatum >= #" & Format(CDate(Me.begindatum), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# And einddatum <= #" & Format(CDate(Me.einddatum), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
End If
```

You can't use BETWEEN here because the dates are in two different fields.

Comment: +1 Yes, the Access Database Engine will always interpret *ambiguous* date literals as `mm/dd/yyyy`. `21/07/2014` (unambiguous because there is no 21st month) will be interpreted as July 21, but `11/07/2014` (ambiguous) will always be interpreted as November 7. To avoid confusion I always recommend using `yyyy/mm/dd` or `yyyy-mm-dd` format for date literals. (BTW, thanks for all of your recent contributions to Stack Overflow. Good work!)

Comment: @GordThompson: No way, man.  Thank YOU for all your contributions, Gord.  You've forgotten more than I will ever know and your humility is amazing.  I am learning so much from you everyday, even in this example.  I appreciate the acknowledgement, but there's no doubt who's doing the heavy lifting around here.  Just happy to learn from you.  Take care.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in the core acces vba works with US format ("mm/dd/yyyy"), i used on my form to filter dates this code, where [Data] is a field from a table :

```
    Function Today()

    Dim dDate As String

    dDate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    strFilter2 = "[Data] = #" & dDate & "#"

    Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form.Filter = strFilter2
    Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form.FilterOn = True

    End Function



    Function ThisWeek()

    dDate = Format(Date - 2, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    dDate2 = Weekday(dDate)
    dDate3 = Date - dDate2

    dDate4 = Format(Date - 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    dDate5 = Weekday(dDate4)
    dDate6 = 7 - dDate5
    dDate7 = Date + dDate6

    strFilter3 = "[Data] between #" & dDate3 & "# AND #" & dDate7 & "#"

    Me.Refresh

    Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form.Filter = strFilter3

    Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form.FilterOn = True

    End Function



    Function ThisMonth()

    dDate = Date - Day(Date) + 1
    dDate2 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)


    dDate3 = Format(dDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    dDate4 = Format(dDate2, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    strFilter3 = "[Data] between #" & dDate3 & "# AND #" & dDate4 & "#"

    Me.Refresh

    Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form.Filter = strFilter3

    Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form.FilterOn = True

    End Function




    Function ThisYear()

    dDate = "1/1/" & Year(Date)
    dDate2 = "31/12/ " & Year(Date)

    dDate3 = Format(dDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    dDate4 = Format(dDate2, "mm/dd/yyyy")


    strFilter3 = "[Data] between #" & dDate3 & "# AND #" & dDate4 & "#"

    Me.Refresh

    Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form.Filter = strFilter3

    Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form.FilterOn = True

    End Function


    Function All()

    'If you have default to show them all

    Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form.FilterOn = False


    End Function
```